# Save AWS glacier downloaded file to amazon s3 location

Tags: php, web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I am creating a PHP api's using glacier php sdk for initiating and downloading. and i have successfully downloaded file in my local server.
Now I want to save downloaded archive file from Glacier to S3 location.

I have done some research and didn't find any possible way please help.

Comment: show us what you have done so far?

Comment: Please follow the guidelines and try and post code samples, and all relevant information relating to your question.

Comment: Isn't it possible to directly (server2server) put the file from one to the other? Downloading locally and uploading costs time and traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be, though with little information it's hard to tell, that you need to investigate the [Amazon AWS PHP SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/) it should contain all of the information you require to PUT files into an S3 bucket